# Android - Отправка изображения на хостинг

Tags: android, api, java, изображения

Приветствую! Пытаюсь отправить картинку [сюда](http://uploads.im/) через их API. В итоге я набросал вот этот код...

```
                File file = new File(path);
                mUtils.log(path);
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://uploads.im/api?format=txt&upload");

                    FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(file, "binary/octet-stream");
                    reqEntity.setContentType("multipart/form-data");
                    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    final String value = EntityUtils.toString(entity).trim(); //тут ответ сервера
                 } catch (Exception ex) { mUtils.log(ex); }
```

...но потом в логах ошибка SocketException EPIPE, ругается на строку `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`. Путь к картинке верный, весит 200кб, по идее сервер должен её распознать. Как мне исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего ты не указал в POST-запросе 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"` имя поля name=""

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://uploads.im/api?format=txt&upload");
                MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder
                        .create();
                multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("имя поля куда отправляется пост запрос",
                        file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
                        "Название изображения");
                post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "UTF-8"));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
```

Пробуй через MultipartEntityBuilder.